# bash linux - issues with functions output

Tags: linux, bash

well , my issue is like that:

```
function abc () {
  var=$(($var + 4));
  echo $var;
}
```

as you see this function , when i use it with "for" loop (`for i in {1..10};  do    abc;  done`) it works and it gives new variable each time
but when i use like this way :

`echo "$(abc) txt $(abc) $(abc)....$(abc)"`

it gives me only the first function's result for all calls ,
and that's my problem , i want it to give new vars :)

Comment: That's because with the statement `$(abc)`, your function is executed in a subshell. Any modifications to variables inside a subshell are not seen by the parent shell. [A good page on subshells](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/SubShell).

Comment: because i'm self learning , i'd no idea about subshells !
thanks a lot for the explanation :)